# How do I use, or set up sonar-project.properties file?

Tags: sonarqube, properties-file, sonar-runner

I have very little exposure to SonarQube but have been asked to make a document explaining how to set up / use  "sonar-project.properties file". Any information or input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here are some resources to get you started

https://www.wrightfully.com/setting-up-sonar-analysis-for-c-projects/ - See Step 6: The sonar-project.properties file.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner

There are also some sample projects on github, you can refer to the project.properties files there as well,
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples

Comment: The first link is quite out of date now, and the second one is not very detailed.  This, although old, is more informative: https://www.devopsschool.com/tutorial/sonarqube/sonarqube-properties.html.

Comment: The second link, even though it looks very official, is dead.
Note that sonar actually recommends using the gui and not the .properties for configuration: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/do-sonarsource-prefer-the-use-of-web-ui-for-project-configuration-if-yes-why/26529

Answer (score 17):

Create a configuration file in the root directory of the project:

- `sonar-project.properties`:

```
# Must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=my-project

# This is the name and version displayed in the SonarQube UI.
# Was mandatory prior to SonarQube 6.1.
sonar.projectName=My project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
 
# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file.
# Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# This property is optional if sonar.modules is set. 
sonar.sources=src
 
# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

##### Reference:

- https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters
- https://www.devopsschool.com/tutorial/sonarqube/sonarqube-properties.html