# Example sonar.properties file for a simple python project

Tags: sonarqube

I am asked to provide sonar.properties file for simple python project. how does the file work and also provide the sample file for understanding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071879/how-do-i-use-or-set-up-sonar-project-properties-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use, or set up sonar-project.properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071879/how-do-i-use-or-set-up-sonar-project-properties-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Project identifier
sonar.projectKey=my-python-project
# Project name
sonar.projectName=My Python Project
# Project version
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
# Source code directory
sonar.sources=src
# Files or directories to exclude
sonar.exclusions=**/tests/**, **/venv/**
# Language for the Python analyzer
sonar.language=py
# SonarQube server URL
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
# SonarQube authentication token (optional, if needed for authentication)
# sonar.login=my-auth-token
# Encoding for Python files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).