# Github Actions add quality gate for test results

Tags: asp.net-core, sonarqube, github-actions, test-coverage, quality-gate

Net core and github actions. I have pipeline running in Github actions and I have integrated Sonarqube. My requirement is if the code coverage is less than 70 or any specified number then we should not allow to continue the build process. Build should stop here. So my current code is

```
SonarQube_API:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Set up Java for Sonar
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'temurin'
          java-version: '17'
          
      - name: Get SonarQube
        shell: pwsh
        run: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner

      - name: Get Coverlet.MSBuild
        shell: pwsh
        run: dotnet add package coverlet.msbuild
        working-directory: '.\JK.Test' 

      - name: .NET sonarscanner begin
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          dotnet sonarscanner begin `
          /k:"JK-Api" `
          /d:sonar.host.url="${{ secrets.MDN_SONARQUBE_HOST }}" `
          /d:sonar.login="${{ secrets.MDN_SONARQUBE_TOKEN }}" `
          /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=".\JK.Test\coverage.opencover.xml" `
          /v:"1.0"
          
        
      - name: build
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          dotnet restore JK.Test/JK.Test.csproj
          dotnet build JK.Test/JK.Test.csproj --configuration '${{ env.BUILD_CONFIG }}' --no-restore

      - name: dotnet test
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          dotnet test ".\JK.Test\JK.Test.csproj" `
            --configuration Release `
            --results-directory "${{ github.workspace }}\TestResults" `
            /p:CollectCoverage=true `
        env:
          CollectCoverage: true
          CoverletOutputFormat: opencover

      - name: .NET sonarscanner end
        shell: pwsh
        run: dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="${{ secrets.MDN_SONARQUBE_TOKEN }}"
```

I am not able to get any informations for my requirement. My requirement is if the code coverage is below for example 70 percent then i would like to fail the build or process should be terminated here itself. Can someone please help me on this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks you

Comment: I would recommend using [sonarqube-quality-gate-action](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube-quality-gate-action). The quality gate value is configured on the SonarQube UI for the project. This action will send the report and wait for the feedback to fail the pipeline or not. [Reference](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/devops-platform-integration/github-integration/#failing-the-pipeline-job-when-the-quality-gate-fails)

Comment: Hi @GuiFalourd Thanks for your reply. So where can I set the threshhold in sonar qube ui? is there any option? Thank you

Comment: On the SonarQube platform, if you have access to the project page and the project configuration, you should be able to manage the quality gate through [these kinds of setting options](https://dx.appirio.com/quality-sonarqube/granting-permissions/SonarQube-QualityGate-2.png). [Reference](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/project-administration/project-settings/#default-issue-assignee)

Comment: @GuiFalourd Yeah Got it. There are many quality gates defines sonar I see. I need to map one quality gate which has my requirements to my project this will be first step right?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you'll indeed need to add a `sonar-project.properties` file to your project. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071879/how-do-i-use-or-set-up-sonar-project-properties-file)

Comment: @GuiFalourd i am getting above error when i run above code You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey. due to this only?

Comment: This error happens when the `sonar-project.properties` file is not in the exact folder where the `sonar-scanner` is executed by the action.

Comment: Yes @GuiFalourd, If i have multiple projects in same repository then how can i have multiple sonar-project.properties files?

Comment: You can by using different `sonar-project.properties`, one for each project (ideally one in each project module package).

Comment: @GuiFalourd please add above comments as answers and i can close this, thanks  a lot again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quality gate value is configured on the **SonarQube UI** for the project.

The [sonarqube-quality-gate-action](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube-quality-gate-action) sends the report and wait for the feedback from the platform to fail the pipeline or not. [Reference](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/devops-platform-integration/github-integration/#failing-the-pipeline-job-when-the-quality-gate-fails)

On the SonarQube platform, if you have access to the project page and the project configuration, you should be able to manage the quality gate through these kinds of setting options:

[image]

[Reference](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/project-administration/project-settings/#default-issue-assignee)

Note that you also will need to create a `sonar-project.properties` file in your project. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071879/how-do-i-use-or-set-up-sonar-project-properties-file)

If you have multiple projects in the same repository, you can add different `sonar-project.properties` file, one for each project (ideally one in each project module package).